# Vue pass props to an element in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a Vue prop to the `a` tag located in the second component. It can be any prop so I can't specifically import that one to the component.

First component

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'first',
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="first">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Second component

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'second',
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <li>
    <a href=""> </a>
  </li>
</template>
```

When I use the component I want to add a prop that gets attached to the `a` tag.

```
<first>
  <second text="test" />
</first>
```

Comment: This question is not well formulated, a directive is not a prop, a directive in vue is only v-something='variable' they are very different than props/attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `v-bind="$attrs"` in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance.

V-bind actually can bind an entire key-value object.

Comment: Sure thing I can look into this. I'm guessing I wouldn't actually be disabling attrs though correct?

Comment: I did a quick test it seems like directives don't show up in $attrs

Comment: What's your version of vue? It's a 2.4 feature. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs

Comment: It should appear in the second component, not the first. And there are two exceptions to it : class and style.